# Storing user input in variables

Tags: c#, methods

This is a method to get user input and store it in variables.
How should I create a second method to access these vars and print them to the console ?
String "who" is used to specify who is that person for example: Teacher or Student or Parent.

```
 static void GetInformation(string who)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the {0} first name: ",who);
    newStudent.firstName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the {0} last name: ",who);
    string lastName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the {0} birthdate: ",who);
    string birthdate = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the {0} address line 1: ",who);
    string addressLine1 = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the {0} address line 2: ",who);
    string addressLine2 = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the {0} city: ",who);
    string city = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the {0} state: ",who);
    string state = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the {0} post code: ",who);
    string postCode = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the {0} country: ",who);
    string country = Console.ReadLine(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class called `Person`, return object of this class filled with the values you collect from `GetInformation` method, and use it as the parameter of another method. Example of the class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName  { get; set; }
    public string Birthdate  { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string Country  { get; set; }
}
```

But I highly suggest you to read some C# tutorial first. This is really basic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you're beginner and the thing you want can easily be done with a Class. However, there's another way.
In the beginning of `GetInformation(string who)` create a new list:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
```

Then, you can add every string you read from the console in the list:

```
list.Add(stringName) //instead of stringName put the variable you want to add
```

In the end of the method call the other method for printing which accepts `List<string>`

In that method use `foreach` and print the elements in the `List<string>`

Answer (score 0):

As every type of data is a string, you should not bother With list<>. Just do Array, which is more of a basic stuff. But storing these into class is much better idea if you can do So. I'm on my phone right now and writing some code Shaft May be hard. Make a class person with void presenting all the data and simply call it on the end of Main(). But as I said before, if you don't feel comfortable with classes yet, try an Array.